# EBNF grammar to ANTLR3?

Tags: parsing, antlr, converters, grammar, ebnf

I have this EBNF grammar for the Jass scripting language.
What needs to be done to convert it to work with ANTLR 3.5?
Furthermore, are there any sort of tools available to aid me in doing so?

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global Declarations
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
program  ::= file+
file     ::= newline? ( declr newline )* func*
declr    ::= typedef
           | globals
           | native_func
typedef  ::= 'type' id 'extends' ( 'handle' | id )
globals  ::= 'globals' newline global_var_list 'endglobals'
global_var_list
         ::= ( 'constant' type id '=' expr newline | var_declr newline )*
native_func
         ::= 'constant'? 'native' func_declr
func_declr
         ::= id 'takes' ( 'nothing' | param_list ) 'returns' ( type | 'nothing' )
param_list
         ::= type id ( ',' type id )*
func     ::= 'constant'? 'function' func_declr newline local_var_list statement_list 'endfunction' newline

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Local Declarations
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
local_var_list
         ::= ( 'local' var_declr newline )*
var_declr
         ::= type id ( '=' expr )?
           | type 'array' id
statement_list
         ::= ( statement newline )*
statement
         ::= set
           | call
           | ifthenelse
           | loop
           | exitwhen
           | return
           | debug
set      ::= 'set' id '=' expr
           | 'set' id '[' expr ']' '=' expr
call     ::= 'call' id '(' args? ')'
args     ::= expr ( ',' expr )*
ifthenelse
         ::= 'if' expr 'then' newline statement_list else_clause? 'endif'
else_clause
         ::= 'else' newline statement_list
           | 'elseif' expr 'then' newline statement_list else_clause?
loop     ::= 'loop' newline statement_list 'endloop'
exitwhen ::= 'exitwhen' expr
return   ::= 'return' expr?
debug    ::= 'debug' ( set | call | ifthenelse | loop )

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Expressions
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
expr     ::= binary_op
           | unary_op
           | func_call
           | array_ref
           | func_ref
           | id
           | const
           | parens
binary_op
         ::= expr ( [+-*/><] | '==' | '!=' | '>=' | '<=' | 'and' | 'or' ) expr
unary_op ::= ( '+' | '-' | 'not' ) expr
func_call
         ::= id '(' args? ')'
array_ref
         ::= id '[' expr ']'
func_ref ::= 'function' id
const    ::= int_const
           | real_const
           | bool_const
           | string_const
           | 'null'
int_const
         ::= decimal
           | octal
           | hex
           | fourcc
decimal  ::= [1-9] [0-9]*
octal    ::= '0' [0-7]*
hex      ::= '$' [0-9a-fA-F]+
           | '0' [xX] [0-9a-fA-F]+
fourcc   ::= '' ' .{4} ' ''
real_const
         ::= [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*
           | '.' [0-9]+
bool_const
         ::= 'true'
           | 'false'
string_const
         ::= '"' .* '"'
parens   ::= '(' expr ')'

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base RegEx
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
type     ::= id
           | 'code'
           | 'handle'
           | 'integer'
           | 'real'
           | 'boolean'
           | 'string'
id       ::= [a-zA-Z] ( [a-zA-Z0-9_]* [a-zA-Z0-9] )?
newline  ::= '\n'+
```

Thanks in advance to any advice offered!

Comment: As it turns out, ANTLR grammars are nearly identical to standard EBNF grammars. [Here's a really good reference guide on understanding ANTLR3 grammars](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Quick+Starter+on+Parser+Grammars+-+No+Past+Experience+Required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't actually use ANTLR, so someone that does might come by with more detailed information.

ANTLR generates recursive descent parsers, so your grammar will have to be refactored to eliminate left recursion, which you have e.g. in `expr`:

```
expr     ::= binary_op
...
binary_op
         ::= expr ( [+-*/><] | '==' | '!=' | '>=' | '<=' | 'and' | 'or' ) expr
```

While parsing `expr`, the parser would try `binary_op` as an option, encounter another `expr`, then try to parse that recursively without having consumed any input, and you would now have infinite recursion.

This is usually dealt with by reformulating the grammar along the lines of

```
expr     ::= binary_op
...
binary_op
         ::= term ( [+-] term )

term = factor ( [*/] factor)

factor = id
         | const
         | parens
         ...
```

and so on.

Not a trivial process, but not impossible to do either.

Comment: ANTLR 4 (http://antlr.org) allows left recursion. Under the covers it performs the necessary refactoring of the grammar before generating the vertical descent parser.

Answer (score 2):

Grammar description languages are really small. The grammars for them have only a dozen or so rules.

What you could do (something I have done) is use ANTLR to write a grammar for the EBNF notation, and use that to to translate what you have into an ANTLR grammar.

It should be about a day of work, or two at most.

Comment: You mean, build a parser that will convert EBNF to ANTLR? If I could do that, then I probably wouldn't need to post this question to begin with. However, if you have already created such a tool, would you mind sharing it here?

Comment: I already did it, but my flavor of EBNF was different from yours, and I have since moved from ANTLR to Grako. Trust me, It will be a day of work or so, and then you can fix it up to keep it, or you can throw it away after it has produced the output you need.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here (or perhaps I am)... If I understood how to do what you suggest, then **I wouldn't have needed to post a question about how to do it**. I am new to ANTLR, so I don't fully understand the differences between EBNF and ANTLR grammar as of yet.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood. There's a direct mapping between EBNF rules and ANTLR rules, as both languages are quite similar. It's a matter of changing symbols here and there (`::=` becomes `:`). The real trick is that you must move lexical rules (rules that deal with characters instead of tokens) into an ANTLR lexer grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for any advice, yet your question is strangely specific to Antlr 3.5.  Do you have a requirement to use Antlr 3.5?  It would help to know what you will be using the grammar for: simple syntax validation or a full-on interpreter?

If you can consider using Antlr 4, you should.  It handles left factored rules better than Antlr 3 and, since it appears that you are just learning Antlr, Antlr 4 IMO will be easier to pick up.  If you really need an AST, then go with Antlr 3

Unfortunately, an automated conversion tool would, at best, give you a bad starting point for developing your grammar.

As to where/how to start, best advise would be to get a copy of the Java grammar ([java.g](https://github.com/antlr/examples-v3) for Antlr 3.5 or [java.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) for Antlr 4) to use as a working example -- Jess appears to sufficiently similar that the java grammar should give you a clear idea of how to proceed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified. I am redefining the language to be more like C/C++, and in order to do so I would first need to be able to parse the original Jass language. Then, I will build a parser & lexer for my own language (based on C), place both parsers in the same C++ library, and then link that library to a console compiler application, capable of interpreting my language into the original Jass scripting language, invented by Blizzard Entertainment. Jass itself has A TON of room for improvement, and I wish to fill those gaps to my own liking.

Comment: I would use Antlr 4, but I've read that now it is solely meant for development in Java... And I'd rather not have to go through the trouble of reinstalling eclipse just for the sole purpose of using Antlr. Antlr 3.5, on the other hand, has a built-in C generator and is the most current version used in ANTLRWorks 1.5, a tool that I'd rather not be without.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment. As it turns out, they have recently developed ANTLRWorks2 ([link](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks)), which uses ANTLR4. It still only targets the java development environment, but the site states that they are working on C++... So I guess I'll stay tuned for that, and meanwhile I suppose I could deal with using eclipse. Possibly even just create an interpreter, if I can make it that far.